# aws-amplify not preserving session after successfull signin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm working on aws-serverless + react app. My problem is with authenticating using `aws-amplify`. Authentication goes fine but session is not preserved.

SigningIn:

```
 await Auth.signIn(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(x => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(x))
            })
            .catch(e => alert(e.message));
```

Response:

```
{
    "username": "xxxxx",
    "pool": {
        "userPoolId": "eu-central-1_xxxxx",
        "clientId": "xxxxx",
        "client": {
            "endpoint": "https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/",
            "userAgent": "aws-amplify/0.1.x js"
        },
        "advancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag": true,
        "storage": {
            "loglevel:webpack-dev-server": "INFO"
        }
    },
    "Session": "xxxxx",
    "client": {
        "endpoint": "https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/",
        "userAgent": "aws-amplify/0.1.x js"
    },
    "signInUserSession": null,
    "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH",
    "storage": {
        "loglevel:webpack-dev-server": "INFO"
    },
    "keyPrefix": "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.xxxxx",
    "userDataKey": "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.xxxxx.xx@x.pl.userData",
    "challengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
    "challengeParam": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "email_verified": "true",
            "phone_number_verified": "true",
            "phone_number": "xxxxx",
            "email": "xx@x.pl"
        },
        "requiredAttributes": []
    }
}
```

After that I make it wait for few seconds. And try to get session data:

```
        try {
            await Auth.currentSession();
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
```

And that gives me error `No current user`

I'm using react+typescript+webpack, Been bashing head over it for 2 days now.

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this problem today. I had created a new user in a (new) Users Pool from AWS console, but after logging in, the session was not persisted (every time I refreshed the page, Auth.currentSession() raised an Error indicating there was no an authenticated user or something like that).

After around one hour I found a solution...

It seems that Amplify does not persist the session when the user needs to update their password (you can see that in the value of `challengeName` field).

What you should do is to let the user know they need to update their password when `challengeName` is `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED`.

To update the password I used

```
await Auth.completeNewPassword(user, newPassword, {});
```

`user` comes from

```
const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password);
```

After doing that, the session is being persisted.

Comment: What a waste of an afternoon. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Wow, more than 3 years later and this is still not resolved in a decent matter. Same here, wasted hours on this. Thanks!